# Missing required parameters for [Route: showbilling] [URI: {locale}/projects/{id}/billings]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I think this is the last problem of my project. I have 2 parameters in 1 route `{locale}/projects/{id}/billings` , the problem is i passed 2 parameter values in view but it still prompts an error with missing required parameters. Here's my code

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('welcome');
    })->name('main');

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    //Customers
    Route::get('/customers', 'CustomerController@showcust')->name('customers');
    Route::post('/sendcust', 'CustomerController@sendcust')->name('sendcust');


    //Items
    Route::get('/items', 'ItemController@showitems')->name('items');
    Route::post('/senditem', 'ItemController@senditem')->name('senditem');

    //Projects
    Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@showprojects')->name('projects');
    Route::post('/sendproj', 'ProjectController@sendproj')->name('sendproj');
    //ProjectBillings
    Route::get('/projects/{id}/billings', 'ProjectController@showbilling')->name('showbilling');
    Route::post('/sendbilling', 'ProjectController@addbilling')->name('sendbilling');   

    //Invoices
    Route::get('/invoices', 'InvoiceController@showinvoice')->name('invoices');
    Route::post('/sendinvoitem', 'InvoiceController@sendinvoitem')->name('sendinvoitem');
    Route::get('/invoices/{id}/details', 'InvoiceController@showdetails');
    Route::post('/updateitem','InvoiceController@updatedetail')->name('updateitem');
    Route::get('invoices/{id}/generate', 'InvoiceController@generate');
    Route::post('/updatestatus', 'InvoiceController@changestatus')->name('updatestatus');

});
```

**projects.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{route('showbilling', ['locale' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => $cat->id])}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs waves-effect waves-float waves-green"> {{__('Add Billing')}} </a>
```

**ProjectController.php**

```
public function showbilling($locale, $id){
   $billings = Project::find($id);
   //return $billings;
   return view('admin.addbillings', compact('billings'));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your routes cache? `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan route:clear`. I occasionally have wonky issues with missing params and I find that it's a 50/50 that cache is the issue.

Comment: yes, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You are passing the parameters incorrectly to the route, The error you are getting is generated at the Router method not at the controller, setting up the router method correctly, it should fix your issue.

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->middleware('setlocale')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/projects/{id}/billings', 'ProjectController@showbilling')->name('showbilling');
})->where('locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}');
```

> Resultant URI /{locale}/project/{id}/billings

Comment: He is using a prefix to add the locale to all routes. `Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']`

Comment: @ImJT, sorry my bad, updated the answer, with the input

Comment: I could be incorrect, but the route itself should become `/{locale}/projects/{id}/billing`. The route prefix would get added to the beginning of the route, not in the middle. You also have an extra /id/ that was not in the original answer.

Comment: @imJT, i got your point, it was typo, i copied the incorrect url from previous answer. but now i have updated it,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this URL:/{locale}/showbilling (Eg:"as/showbilling") instead now you use. The {locale} is efficient in router group. So, I guess you forget this one.